# Disable Android test orchestrator for specific product flavour

Tags: android

Right now I have test orchestrator set in gradle

```
android {
    testOptions {
        execution = 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
    }
}
```

Is it possible to disable this for a specific product flavour?